# jquery autoselect datepicker on load

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My page has a calendar (jquery datepicker) with only one date available to user selection, by default is obviously that user select the date because has only one available.

[image]

The question is: is possible select automatically the date available when page is loading, in the source, the date available has a class `bookable`

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month bookable" title="This date is available" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary" href="#">2</a></td>
```

I'need to hide this calendar and autoselect date

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".bookable" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

You can read the documentation on [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) .Basically the above code will set the date to 12/12/2012

Comment: I don't need to set the date to other date, i need to autoselect date